# Can't get JSON from http request

Tags: java, json, web-services, jersey-2.0

I implemented a RESTful web-service based on Jersey.
When sending my request I first check if some mandatory parameters are defined and if not I return a Response with an error code and an error message.
Here is the snippet:

```
@Path( "/groups" )
@RequestScoped
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Produces( value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML} )
public class GroupResource
{
  ...
  @POST
  public Response createGroup( Group group, @Context UriInfo uriInfo )
  {
    logger.info("-------------------");
    logger.info("Create group");
    logger.fine(group.toString());
    logger.info("-------------------");

    // check mandatory fields
    if (!checkMandatoryFields(group, errorMessages))
    {
      return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(errorMessages).build();
    }
  ...
}
```

I then implemented a JUnit test to test it:

```
@Test
  public void testCreateGroup()
  {
    try
    {
      URL url = new URL(URL_GROUPS_WS);

      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

      String json2send = "{\"grid\":\"1\", \"gidNumber\":\"2\", \"groupName\":\"TestGroup\", \"groupDescription\":\"Initial description\", \"targetSystems\":[\"ADD TS1\"]}";

      OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
      os.write(json2send.getBytes());
      os.flush();

      System.out.println("XXXXXXXX Sending request XXXXXXXX \n");

      if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200)
      {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer error = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
          error.append(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();

        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode() + error.toString());
      }
  ...
}
```

My problem is that I get the `responseCode`, but I don't know how to get the error message, which should be somewhere in the response, right? (`Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(**errorMessages**).build()`).

The above code, where I check the response code, doesn't work...

Could you please help me?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" precisely. What do you expect to happen, wand what happens instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how to test a **jersey** component properly, indeed you are supposed to rely on the [`Jersey Test Framework`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html) to test a component as it hides a lot of complexity such that your unit test is easy to read and maintain.

Your current code is **much too error prone and should be avoided**.

Assuming that you use `maven`, you need to add the next 2 dependencies to your project with the `test` scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.24</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.24</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you can simply make your unit test extends [`JerseyTest`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.24/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/test/JerseyTest.html) and override the method `configure` to provide the class of your rest component, and it is done for the environment's setup. It will automatically launch a grizzly sever and bind your component for you, so the only thing left to do is to write your unit test(s).

**Your test class could be something like that:**

```
public class GroupResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(GroupResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateGroup() {
        Group group = // create your group instance to test here
        Response response = target("/groups")
            .request()
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(group, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        Assert.assertEquals(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST, response.getStatus());
        Assert.assertEquals("My error message", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of InputStream, use ErrorStream -

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
```

ErrorStream will give you response in case of error.